# How to fetch data from telegram having channel name/title using Telethon?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

How can I fetch data from telegram's public channel using Telethon. I have channel name and I don't have channel ID or channel username.

Example: for the telegram channel, **Kadyrov_95**, ID is **1141171940**, title is **Kadyrov_95** and username is **RKadyrov_95**

I know if I have channel ID or channel username, I can fetch rest of channel details. But, how can I do the same if I only have channel name/title i.e Kadyrov_95

Kindly assist. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As any Telegram clients, the only option left is to search it globally, in case you aren't a member of said chat.

see [`SearchRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/contacts/search.html) and the code block underneath the page.

and if you only need channels, access the .chats in the [response](https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/contacts/found.html) (if a chat was found).

```
if r := result.chats:
    print(r[0].username)
```